# Java: validate magnet-link

Tags: java, validation, magnet-uri

I'm looking for some validator for magnet-link in Java, something like [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) from Apache Commons Validator project for HTTP URLs, but all what I found is approaches with regular expressions. As another one option I see  - to use some torrent processing library and try to open the link, but it seems pretty heavy operation.

Is there some common approach for this case except regexes?

Comment: What is wrong with regexp approach?

Comment: @fxrbfg Two main regex disadvantages for me - it makes the code difficult to read and code without regex more easy to debug and to test. So I prefer to use libraries for validation when it's possible.

Comment: @hlebnotbread, documentation above the regex or wrapping it in a well named method will help alleviate some of the pain when working with a regex. A method can also be tested as a single unit. As long as the method is tested and documented, you can treat it as a black box.

Comment: @masterwok thanks for your remark, I fully agree with you